# How can centre of mass be virtual?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, mass

Today I was reading a book for high school physics and in that book it was written that *the center of mass of an object can be real or virtual i.e. it may or may not have mass at that point*, however, I am unable to understand that how could COM be virtual? Do we assume it such so that it is easier to solve problems? Any help or insight will be appreciated!

Comment: The COM of a horseshoe would be non material.

Comment: Or a doughnut (i.e. the center is in the hole)

Comment: This is not, in my opinion, a common or particularly useful term. What book is this?

Comment: I agree with trentcl. Since the centre of mass is a single point, it has zero volume, so it doesn't actually matter whether there is mass there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By "virtual" the author means "non-material." The center of mass can be a material point or a non-material point.

For example, the center of mass for a solid sphere is a material point. It is coincident with a material point of the body.

The center of mass for a hollow sphere is a non-material point. It floats in space and is not coincident with a material point of the body.

Comment: A donut also works well to visualize this.

Comment: A sphere _is_ hollow: all points **equal** (not less than or equal) to the radius distance.  A _ball_ is the solid shape.

Comment: @JDługosz erm, maybe in some other world language, but I think you'd have trouble convincing an English native speaker of the validity of your claim "a sphere is hollow, a ball is solid".. Evan's use of "hollow sphere" and "solid sphere" is a correct distinction

Comment: @CaiusJard In mathematics, "ball" for the solid object and "sphere" for the hollow object is the standard terminology.  Outside of mathematics (even in physics), "sphere" is usually used for both.

Comment: It is vastly safer to refer to "hollow sphere" or "surface of a ball", to disambiguate from "solid ball", in mathematical practice, in my experience. Sure, sometimes context makes it clear, but there's no completely universal time-invariant convention.

Comment: "Ball" doesn't even assume that the shape is a sphere. (Gridiron football, Rugby)

Comment: @CaiusJard With the context of center of mass calculations in physics, I naturally take the language to be "math mode".  After all, if you used words like "momentum" with their fuzzy casual meaning rather than (only) the precise physics meaning, in a class on Newtonian mechanics, people would be very confused.

Comment: Ping pong ball is not solid.